# Fragments losing value in viewPager in android

Tags: android, json, android-viewpager

I am using viewPager in a Fragment. Viewpager contains 5 
fragments named  1) General 2) ozone 3) Myzone 4) Bizzone 5) Password.
All the fragments are getting value from json and its working well.
First fragments (general) is dealing with 4 different api in which 3
are dedicated to three different spinners and 1 is to get the final
values for complete view.

Now the question is, I swap the views by viewPager and reach to last
fragment, when I come to the first view, it loses the value of Spinner
and they become empty.

This is the code which I am using to set the values in view.

public class ProfileGeneralSetting extends Fragment implements MiFeelingBase, OnClickListener{

```
public Spinner spCountryName;
public Spinner spCityName;
public Spinner spTimeZone;
private RadioGroup rg1;
private RadioButton rbEnable, rbDisable;

public Button SettingSaveGeneral;


public EditText edGeneralFullname,edGeneralEmail,edGeneralFirstName,edGeneralLastName,edGeneralMobileNumber,edGeneralAddress1,
edGeneralAddress2,edtUser_Dob,edtEducationInstitude,edtDegree,edtGrade,edtStartYear,edtEndYear,edtStream;

public int mYear;
public int mMonth;
public int mDay;


ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
ArrayList<Country> countryList = new ArrayList<Country>();
ArrayList<Country>cityList=new ArrayList<Country>();
ArrayList<Country>timeList=new ArrayList<Country>();
GeneralSettingData generalList = new GeneralSettingData();
private GeneralSettingAdapter adapter;
private GeneralSettingAdapter2 adapter2;
private GeneralSettingAdapter3 adapter3;
//private GeneralSettingAdapter4 adapter4;

Context context;

public ImageView Usercalender;
private static final int DATE_DIALOG_ID = 0;

private String strUserID;
private int index=0;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.profilesettinggeneral, container, false);



    rg1 = (RadioGroup)rootView.findViewById(R.id.rg1);
    spCountryName = (Spinner)rootView.findViewById(R.id.spCountryName);
    spCityName = (Spinner)rootView.findViewById(R.id.spCityName);
    spTimeZone = (Spinner)rootView.findViewById(R.id.spTimeZone);

    edGeneralFullname = (EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.edGeneralFullname);
    edGeneralEmail = (EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.edGeneralEmail); 
    edGeneralFirstName = (EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.edGeneralFirstName);
    edGeneralLastName = (EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.edGeneralLastName);
    edGeneralMobileNumber = (EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.edGeneralMobileNumber);
    edGeneralAddress1 = (EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.edGeneralAddress1);
    edGeneralAddress2 = (EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.edGeneralAddress2);
    edtUser_Dob = (EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.edtUser_Dob);
    edtEducationInstitude = (EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.edtEducationInstitude);
    edtDegree = (EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.edtDegree);
    edtGrade = (EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.edtGrade);
    edtStartYear = (EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.edtStartYear);
    edtEndYear = (EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.edtEndYear);
    edtStream = (EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.edtStream);
    Usercalender = (ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.Usercalender);
    rbEnable = (RadioButton)rootView.findViewById(R.id.rbEnable);
    rbDisable = (RadioButton)rootView.findViewById(R.id.rbDisable);

    SettingSaveGeneral = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.SettingSaveGeneral);

    SettingSaveGeneral.setOnClickListener(this);

    Usercalender.setOnClickListener(this);

    rbEnable.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "enabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });

    rbDisable.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "disabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });


    /*rg1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener(){

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            if(checkedId == R.id.rbEnable){

                Toast.makeText(context, "enabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else if(checkedId == R.id.rbDisable){

                Toast.makeText(context, "disabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
    });*/

    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);


    Usercalender.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            final Calendar c =  Calendar.getInstance();
            mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

            DatePickerDialog dpd = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener(){

                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                        int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth){

                    edtUser_Dob.setText(year + "-"+ (monthOfYear + 1) + "-" + dayOfMonth);
                }


            }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
            dpd.show();



        }
    });


    //spCountryName.("Counrty");
    APIAccess.fetchData(ProfileGeneralSetting.this, getActivity(), getActivity());


    return rootView;

}




@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

     AppContoller.getInstance().pref=getActivity().getSharedPreferences(AppContoller.getInstance().PREF_NAME, 0);

        strUserID=AppContoller.getInstance().pref.getString(AppContoller.getInstance().USER_ID, "0");
        APIAccess.fetchData(ProfileGeneralSetting.this, getActivity(), getActivity());

        savedInstanceState

        /*rg1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener(){

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                if(checkedId == R.id.rbEnable){

                    Toast.makeText(context, "enabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }else if(checkedId == R.id.rbDisable){

                    Toast.makeText(context, "disabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }
        });*/



}



@Override
public String httpPost() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    String response="";
    if(index==0)
    {
    response=OpenConnection.callUrl(StaticData.SABAKUCH_GENERAL_SETTING_COUNTRY);

    }else if(index==1)
    {
        response=OpenConnection.callUrl(StaticData.SABAKUCH_GENERAL_SETTING_CITY);


    }else if(index==2)
    {
        response=OpenConnection.callUrl(StaticData.SABAKUCH_GENERAL_SETTING_TIMEZONE);
    }

    else if(index==3)
    {

        response = OpenConnection.callUrl(StaticData.SABAKUCH_GENERAL_SETTING_GETDATA+strUserID);
    }

    //Log.d("RespoNCEEEEEEEEE", response);
    return response;
}

@Override
public String httpAfterPost(String str) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if(str!=null)
    {
        if(index==0){

        countryList=SabaKuchParse.parseCountryData(str);

        if(countryList.size()>0)
        {
            adapter=new GeneralSettingAdapter(getActivity(), countryList);
            spCountryName.setAdapter(adapter);
            index=1;
            APIAccess.fetchData(ProfileGeneralSetting.this, getActivity(), getActivity());
        }

     }else if(index==1)
     {

         cityList=SabaKuchParse.parseCityData(str);

            if(cityList.size()>0)
            {
                adapter2=new GeneralSettingAdapter2(getActivity(), cityList);
                spCityName.setAdapter(adapter2);
                index=2;
                APIAccess.fetchData(ProfileGeneralSetting.this, getActivity(), getActivity());
            }

     }else if(index==2)
     {
         timeList = SabaKuchParse.parseTimeData(str);

         if(timeList.size()>0){

             adapter3 = new GeneralSettingAdapter3(getActivity(),timeList);

             spTimeZone.setAdapter(adapter3);

             index=3;
             APIAccess.fetchData(ProfileGeneralSetting.this, getActivity(), getActivity());

         }
     }

     else if(index==3)
     {
         generalList = SabaKuchParse.parseFullData(str);

    edGeneralFullname.setText(generalList.strFname);
    edGeneralEmail.setText(generalList.strEmail);
    String tt = generalList.strEmail;

    Log.d("helloooooooooooooooooooo", tt);
    edGeneralFirstName.setText(generalList.strFname);
    edGeneralLastName.setText(generalList.strlname);
    edGeneralMobileNumber.setText(generalList.strContact);
    edGeneralAddress1.setText(generalList.strAddress1);
    edGeneralAddress2.setText(generalList.strAddress2);
    edtUser_Dob.setText(generalList.strDob);
    edtEducationInstitude.setText(generalList.arr.get(0).strSchool);
    edtDegree.setText(generalList.arr.get(0).strDegree);
    edtGrade.setText(generalList.arr.get(0).strGrade);
    edtStartYear.setText(generalList.arr.get(0).strFrom_date);
    edtEndYear.setText(generalList.arr.get(0).strTo_date);
    edtStream.setText(generalList.arr.get(0).strField_study);


    String ss = generalList.strTime_zone;
    Log.d("jhakkasss", ss);

    for(int i=0;i<timeList.size();i++)
    {
    if( timeList.get(i).strTimezoneid.equalsIgnoreCase(generalList.strTime_zone))
        {
            spTimeZone.setSelection(i);
        }
    }


    for(int i=0;i<countryList.size();i++)
    {
        if( countryList.get(i).strCountryid.equalsIgnoreCase(generalList.strCountry_id))
        {
            spCountryName.setSelection(i);
        }

    }

    for(int i=0;i<cityList.size();i++)
    {
        if(cityList.get(i).strCityid.equalsIgnoreCase(generalList.strCity_id))
        {
            spCityName.setSelection(i);
        }
    }


     }else if(index==5){
     }

    }

    return null;
    }


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.SettingSaveGeneral:

        index =5;

        APIAccess.fetchData(ProfileGeneralSetting.this, getActivity(), getActivity());
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }

}
}
```

this is my Main fragment class where I have created viewPager

```
public class ProfileSettingFragment extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment implements TabListener {

private ViewPager mPager;
private MyPageAdapter adapter;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.profile_setting_fragment, container, false);

         mPager=(ViewPager)rootView.findViewById(R.id.pager);

            mPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);
            adapter=new MyPageAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
            mPager.setAdapter(adapter);


            TabPageIndicator indicater=(TabPageIndicator)rootView.findViewById(R.id.indicator1);
            indicater.setViewPager(mPager);

            indicater.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onPageSelected(int arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
            });

            /*mPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
            });*/

            /*actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("Home").setTabListener(this));
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("MiZone").setTabListener(this));
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("Top Trending").setTabListener(this));
            actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);*/

            return rootView;
    }

    private class MyPageAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter
       {
            private List<android.support.v4.app.Fragment> fragments;

        public MyPageAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            this.fragments=new ArrayList<android.support.v4.app.Fragment>();
            fragments.add(new ProfileGeneralSetting());
            fragments.add(new ProfileOzoneSetting());
            fragments.add(new ProfileMyzoneSetting());
            fragments.add(new ProfileBizzoneSetting());
            fragments.add(new ProfilePasswordSetting());


        }

        @Override
        public android.support.v4.app.Fragment getItem(int arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return fragments.get(arg0);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return "General";
                case 1:
                    return "Ozone";
                case 2:
                    return "MyZone";
                case 3:
                    return "BizZone";
                case 4 :
                    return "Password Setting";
            }
             return null;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return fragments.size();
        }

       }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        mPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's strange that although you are using `mPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);` your fragments are still recreated. Are you sure there isn't a data loading problem in your fragments?

Comment: I Don't know, as I have mentioned in my question that there are 4 different api running on this page.

Comment: You can change the `setOffscreenPageLimit` to 1. In this case, when your 3th fragment is active, your first and last fragment should be destroyed. If the data is refilled when you selet the first and last pages, I believe your data-loading is ok. Then you should follow the @Kuffs' suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved my problem. I added this code of line to my fragment.

```
 @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDestroyView();

        index =0;

        APIAccess.fetchData(ProfileGeneralSetting.this, getActivity(), getActivity());
    }
```

and also change this `mPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);` into this `mPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);`

Now its working properly as I want. 
Thanks every one for your kind help.:)

Comment: With the offscreenpagelimit, you're keeping all your fragments in memory, good luck with OOM that will happen soon!

Answer (score 0):

When a fragment is no longer displayed, it may be shut down by the system.

You can save their state using `OnSaveInstanceState` or make use of call `setRetainInstance(true)` in your fragment `OnCreate`

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setRetainInstance(boolean)

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onSaveInstanceState(android.os.Bundle)

Comment: Please see my full code and let me know where to set setRetainInstance(true)??

Comment: In your fragment OnCreate as already stated. Please read the supplied documentation links for full details.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't post the code for your fragments, but I bet you are not saving their state.

In your `httpAfterPost()` method, it looks like you are creating the spinner adapter then sending it to the fragment.  In the fragment, you need to access the list data that the adapter has and save it by overriding `onSaveInstanceState()`, then bringing the data back in `onCreate()` from the `savedInstanceState` bundle.

It might be better to pass the data to the fragment and let it create the adapter, rather than creating the adapter first and handing it to the fragment.  Either way, you have to get at that list data and save/restore it.

1. In order to be saved, your `Country` class needs to implement either `Serializable` or `Parcelable`, which is Android DIY serialization.
2. Override `onSavedInstanceState()`

   ```
   @Override
   public void onSavedInstanceState(Bundle outstate) {
       outState.putSerializable("countryList", (Serializable) countryList);  // if Country implements Serializable
       // or
       outState.putParcelable("countryList", (Parcelable) countryList);
       super.onSavedInstanceState(outState);
   }
   ```
3. In `onCreate()`, add this line:

   ```
   countryList = (ArrayList<Country>) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("countryList");
   ```

   or

   ```
   countryList = (ArrayList<Country>) savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList("countryList");
   ```

   Also recreate your spinner adapters here once you have your list back.

Repeat this for all the spinner adapter lists that are disappearing.

Comment: I have posted my edited question with full code. Please have a look and let me know how to do this.